# Macro to copy and paste from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook where I need to be able to click on a single cell of a worksheet and hit my command button. That copies and pastes the cell value to the first blank cell in column E on a different worksheet within the same workbook. When I just run the macro by itself, it works fine. But when I paste the code into a command button, it gives me a couple of runtime error 1004's. The most common error is "Select method of range class failed" and refers to the code line that tells it to select Range (E4). Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Choose player from Player list and  paste to Draft list.

    Sheets("Players").Select
    Selection.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Draft").Select
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial _ 
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: It will also give me an error if cells E4 and E5 aren't filled it. I know this is because of the ctrl+down arrow and offset commands, but I don't know how else to make it search for the next blank cell. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried Sheets("Players").Range("E4").Select

Comment: Why don't you just assign the macro to a button? As in put the sub in a module, then put a button in your sheet and assign that sub as the assigned macro? If the sub works fine I don't see why it wouldn't work fine if called by a button. You also don't have to select so many things, it slows down your code tremendously.

Comment: I just tried that. Same error. Do I need to add error handling code to this? And if so, what would that look like?

Comment: I had changed the code in the command button to "call click_player" to just call and run the macro. That worked fine on my computer, but when I tried it on a different computer, it gave me the runtime error.

Comment: `Selection.Select` might be the worst thing I've ever seen related to Excel.  That's like saying "that thing that you are: keep being that thing"  It's completely wasteful.

Comment: @Paradox, that would have worked if it was `Sheets("Draft").Range("E4").Select`.  I think you missed that the `ActiveSheet` changed to `Draft`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**, couple options to resolve this, in order of preference:

1. [Stop using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4288101) to access cells
2. Qualify your call to `Range("E4")` when executing code in a `Worksheet` object by using `Application.Range("E4")` or `Sheets("Draft").Range("E4")` or `ActiveSheet.Range("E4")`
3. Move the code to `ThisWorkbook` or a code module and call that `Sub` from the event.

---

Here is the lengthy part that attempts to explain *why* your code does not work.

This all comes down to: where is the code executing?  Different execution contexts will behave differently when you use unqualified references to `Cells` `Range` and a number of other functions.

Your original code likely ran inside `ThisWorkbook`, a code module, or possibly in the code file for sheet `Draft`.  Why do I guess this?  Because in all of those places a call to `Range("E4")` would be acceptable to get the cell `E4` on sheet `Draft`.  Cases:

- `ThisWorkbook`and a code module will execute `Range` on the `ActiveSheet` which is `Draft` since you just called `Select` on it.
- Inside `Draft` will execute `Range` in the context of `Draft` which is acceptable since that is the `ActiveSheet` and the place where you are trying to get cell `E4`.

Now what happens when we add an ActiveX `CommandButton` to the mix?  Well that code is added to the `Worksheet` where it lives. This means that the code for the button can possibly execute in a different context than it did before.  The only exception to this is if the button and code are both on sheet `Drafts`, which I assume not since you `Select` that sheet.  For demonstrations, let's say the button is located on sheet `WHERE_THE_BUTTON_IS`.

Given that sheet, what is going on now?  Your call to `Range` is now executed in the context of sheet `WHERE_THE_BUTTON_IS` **regardless** of the `ActiveSheet` or anything else you do outside of the call to `Range`.  This is because the call to `Range` is *unqualified*.  That is, there is no object to provide scope to the call so it runs in the current scope which is the `Worksheet`.

So now we have a call to `Range("E4")` in sheet `WHERE_THE_BUTTON_IS` which is trying to `Select` the cell.  This is forbidden because sheet `Draft` is the `ActiveSheet` and

> **Thou shalt not `Select` a cell on a `Worksheet` that is not the `ActiveSheet`**

So with all of this, how do we resolve this issue?  There are a couple of ways out:

1. **[Stop using `Select` to manipulate cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4288101)**.  This gets away from the main problem here, quoted above.  This assumes your button lives on the same sheet as the `Selection` to copy/paste.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Draft").Range("E4").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = Selection.Value

End Sub
```

---

2. **Qualify the call to `Range`** so that it executes in the proper context and chooses the right cell.  You can use the `Sheets("Draft").Range` object to qualify this or `Application.Range` instead of the bare `Range`.  I highly recommend option 1 instead of trying to figure out how to make `Select` work.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Players").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Draft").Select

    'could also use Application.Range here
    Sheets("Draft").Range("E4").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

---

3. Move the code back to a `Sub` that is outside of the `Worksheet` object and call it from the `CommandButton1_Click` event.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Sheets("Draft").Range("E4").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value2 = ActiveCell.Value2
End Sub
```

My motto: if it doesn't have a `Select` method it can't have a `Select` method error.
Fun fact: even if it's working properly, it will replace your existing values if `E4` is empty. I recommend using `LastRow` instead (I like the `Range("E:E").Find`one the most).

Comment: This will not work if the desired `Range` to copy/paste is larger than one cell.  `ActiveCell` always refers to a single cell regardless of the size of the `Selection`.  I agree with your assessment of `Select` though.

Comment: " I need to be able to click on a single cell of a worksheet and hit my command button" - OP. If it doesn't work, the specification was bad.

Comment: Good eye.  I already upvoted but now I agree fully with this answer.

Comment: Can u give an example of what you mean when you say use LastColumn and Range ("e:e").Find? I don't know how to incorporate it into the code listed above. On my Draft sheet, E1 is actually E1-E3 merged. Also, I used the freeze panes function on the top three rows, if that makes a difference.

Comment: `LastRow = Range("E:E").Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` sorry, I wrote *LastColumn* in lieu of *LastRow*.